# fBasics::fitStable working suspiciously

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, quantitative-finance

I've been working with the **`fBasics`** package respectively a **`fitStable`** function to fit some series to a more general, stable distributions.

There are two approaches - a **quantile method**, proposed by [McCulloh](http://www.econ.ohio-state.edu/jhm/papers/stabparm.pdf)
and then there is the **MLE** approach.

The function offers both, but the MLE approach is really, really slow and sometimes it even does not compute - and yields **`NA`**.

It uses **`nlminb`** to maximise the likelihood function ( think it minimises the -likelihood fun ).

But even if it has finished after a long time, the estimate for 1000 observations from standard normal ( for which it should have given the values of `(2,0,1,0)` ) it gives:

```
Estimated Parameter(s):
     alpha       beta      gamma      delta 
1.99990000 0.22448469 0.71247528 0.02995476
```

where I would have expected, at least for the **`beta`** to be closer to zero.

Does anyone have any experience to share?

Any idea, how to speed this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this with 20 runs of 100 (instead of 1000). Got a lot of betas close to zero (as expected), but some close to -1. Also the gammas are fairly consistent. Time elapsed was 10 minutes.

```
library(fBasics)
set.seed(100)
x <- rnorm(1000)
a <- vector(,20)
b <- vector(,20)
c <- vector(,20)
d <- vector(,20)

system.time(
for(i in 1:20){
    samp <- sample(x, size = 100, replace = T)
    v <- stableFit(samp, type='mle')
    a[i] <- (v@fit)$estimate[1]
    b[i] <- (v@fit)$estimate[2]
    c[i] <- (v@fit)$estimate[3]
    d[i] <- (v@fit)$estimate[4]
}
)
```

System Time:
 user  system elapsed
 598.67    1.49  602.80

```
a
```

1.8070, 1.9999, 1.9999, 1.9140, 1.9999, 1.9999, 1.9999, 1.9999, 1.9999, 1.8967, 1.9999, 1.9999, 1.9999, 1.9999, 1.9999, 1.9999, 1.9999, 1.9999, 1.9999, 1.8166

```
b
```

-0.9999, 0.1247, 0.0070, -0.9999, 0.0026, 0.0177, 0.0083 0.0409, 0.0179, 0.3062, 0.8251, -0.0769, 0.0071, -0.7928, -0.9225, -0.0147, -0.7459, -0.0191, 0.0016, -0.9999

```
c
```

0.7121, 0.7337, 0.7654, 0.7287, 0.8393, 0.6441, 0.7475, 0.7113, 0.7204, 0.6475, 0.7065, 0.7408, 0.7269, 0.7191, 0.6453, 0.6824, 0.6815, 0.7642, 0.7970, 0.6347

```
d
```

0.1576, 0.1092, -0.0115, 0.0196, 0.2325, 0.1222, 0.2546, -0.0610, 0.0873, 0.0438 -0.0120, -0.1266, 0.1631, 0.1443, -0.0793, -0.1651, 0.1649, 0.0891, -0.0043, 0.1259

Comment: yh thanks, I'm gettting the same results, the are alright, my biggest problem now is however how to speed it up, because it takes too much time and I need about 100 of them, with longer series...Quite slow is the calculating the density of stable distribution, will keep digging deeper.

Comment: You're right. It's probably nlminb. I don't think it's boundary convergence slowness. Gaussian has a = 2, and a is in (0,2]. I tried it with `rcauchy(100)`, (a,b,c,d) = (1,0,1,0), and Levy `rstable(100, alpha=0.5, beta=1)` from package `stabledist`. Cauchy took 520 seconds (Gaussian 603 s). Levy stopped with an error, but had estimates close to (0.5,1,1,0)